# What is meant by "Deep Learning models are not understood"?

Tags: deep-learning, philosophy, agi

It is a sentence that I hear a lot and I guess I don't get what it means.

It seems that the weight optimization procedure is very well understood and there is, to some extent, theoretical/empirical foundations that justify the different techniques.

So what exactly about DNNs is not understood?

Any pointing to a reference would already be helpful.

Comment: What's definitely not understood: in which part of the matrix multiplications does sentient thought occur?

Comment: Usually this is referring to Explainability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are broadly two phenomena that are often referred to as not understanding deep learning:

1. It is not well understood how the network arrives at any particular solution. Trying to analyze the weights into human understandable knowledge is often futile. The model acts as a black box: it seems to do well, but we do not understand the rules it uses to operate. The field of AI that attempts to deal with this is called [explainability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explainable_artificial_intelligence).
2. It is not well understood why neural networks, which are heavily over parametrized, do not seem to overfit. The field of study that attempts to tackle this is called [Computational Learning Theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_learning_theory).